# Hive split two identical Jsons separated by comma in single file

Tags: json, regex, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I have two Jsons which are attached as below.our production systems aggregating multiple Jsons into single file as below. my problem here is how to split the jsons which are in a single separated by comma(i,e 1&2) and remove 3 from the file. the difference between 1,2 and 3 is 3 doesnot have the condition ID

```
 1---{name:string,
        actid: string,
        data:array<struct>,
        conditionId:string
     },
 2---{name:string,
        actid: string,
        data:array<struct>,
        conditionId:string
     },
 3---{name:string,
        actid:string,
       data:array<struct>
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file with data as

```
1--- {name:string, actid: string, data:array, conditionId:string }, 2---{name:string, actid: string, data:array, conditionId:string}, 3---{name:string, actid:string, data:array}
```

And if you are looking to `filter` malformed json as `3` and save the file as valid `json` file then you can use following codes in `spark`

```
val data = sc.textFile("path to the malformed input file")
data.flatMap(line => line.split("---"))
  .map(array => array.split(","))
  .filter(_.length > 3)
  .map(array => conditions(array(0).split(":")(1), array(1).split(":")(1), array(2).split(":")(1), array(3).split(":")(1).replace("}", "")))
  .toDF()
  .write.json("path to output json file")
```

You should have a file with valid json as

```
{"name":"string","actid":" string","data":"array","conditionId":"string "}
{"name":"string","actid":" string","data":"array","conditionId":"string"}
```

Comment: @RameshMaharajan Thank you for the response is there any way to make it dynamically filter the malformed json because there files which had 3 occured between 6-10

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your problem. Can you give an example.?